# Intellij can't access /usr/local on Mac (10.7.5)

Tags: macos, permissions, intellij-idea

My copy of Intellij IDEA CE 12.0.1 (Build 123.94) can't access `/usr/local`. I scoured the internet and no one else had this problem before. I know that it has something to do with folder permissions because IDEA can access the folder when I ran using sudo. My workaround was to match the folder permissions to a folder accessible to IDEA, but it didn't resolve the issue. The current permissions are as follows:

```
$ drwxr-xr-x@ 25 sergeykoulikov  staff  850 14 Dec 12:24 /usr/local
```

Which is almost the same as my Inbox folder, which IDEA can access.

```
$ drwxr-xr-x  10 sergeykoulikov  staff  340 12 Jan 17:05 /Users/sergeykoulikov/Inbox
```

What am I missing? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question doesn't have enough information to give a specific answer, but I can point you at things to investigate. First, the "@" after the permissions on /usr/local indicates it has extended attributes, and maybe also an access control list (essentially, extended permissions); it's also possible the folder may have flags set, which can change its behavior. To see all of these things, use `ls -ldeO@ /usr/local`

If that doesn't point you at the problem, clarify what you mean by "access". *Exactly* what is IDEA doing in the two folders? Is it doing (/trying to do) the same thing in both folders? Is it trying to access the files inside the folders, and if so are the permissions on the files the same and/or is there a file that's present in one folder but not the other that's causing the difference?

Comment: I am using IDEA as my Erlang IDE and all the Erlang related stuff is installed in /usr/local. So when I try to set the project SDK for a newly created project by navigating to /usr/local, I get a brief flash of the folder's contents in IDEA and the location get changed to my home folder. I have run your shell command and it revealed the presence of com.apple.quarantine on the folder. I'll try removing it and see whether the problem gets fixed.

Comment: I have removed the com.apple.quarantine on /usr/local but the issue is still there. The workaround for me was to run IDEA in "sudo" mode and set the default Erlang SDK for all projects. This way, when I create a new Erlang project the SDK is already configured. I tested with a code sample and everything compiles fine. Strange ...